# Is it possible for a Master page to access Controller properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, master-pages, controller

I need to load a HTML wrapper dynamically depending on data that gets populated in the `PageController`, which is a base class that all other controllers implement.

This is the PageController:

```
public class PageController : Controller
{
    protected PageConfiguration PageConfiguration;
    public string WrapperTop { get; set; }
    public string WrapperBottom { get; set;}

    protected override void Initialize(RequestContext rc)
    {

        // the PageConfiguration is determined by the 
        // Controller that is being called
        var pageName = rc.RouteData.Values.Values.FirstOrDefault();
        this.PageConfiguration = GetPageConfiguration(pageName.ToString());

        WrapperManager wm = GetWrapperManager(this.PageConfiguration.Id);
        this.WrapperTop = wm.WrapperPartOne;
        this.WrapperBottom = wm.WrapperPartTwo;

        base.Initialize(rc);
    }
}
```

I'm currently implementing my Master page as follows:

```
<% Html.RenderAction( "GetWrapperTop", "FundFactsheet"); %>

    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>    

<% Html.RenderAction("GetWrapperBottom", "FundFactsheet"); %>
```

But this means that I have to have `GetWrapperTop()` & `GetWrapperBottom()` defined in all Controllers that need a wrapper, and I also have to have a Master page for every type of Wrapper that I want. For instance, the Master page for SearchResultsController would have:

```
<% Html.RenderAction("GetWrapperBottom", "SearchResults"); %>
```

Ideally it'd just be

```
<%= this.WrapperTop %>

    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>    

<%= this.WrapperBottom %>
```

How can the Master page access the `WrapperTop` and `WrapperBottom` values in `PageController`?

Comment: Is this not a bit of an abuse of MVC? Surely if you're dynamically varying the display to this degree you should be rendering different views, not forcing a master page to deal with this logic.

Comment: But the Master page needs to contain the wrapper around `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">`. Are you suggesting that I should have multiple Master pages? One for the FundFactsheet Index View? and one for SearchResults Index View?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the following worked, which I figured out from [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/passing-data-to-view-master-pages-cs)

```
public class PageController : Controller
{
    protected PageConfiguration PageConfiguration;
    public string WrapperTop { get; set; }
    public string WrapperBottom { get; set;}

    protected override void Initialize(RequestContext rc)
    {

        // the PageConfiguration is determined by the 
        // Controller that is being called
        var pageName = rc.RouteData.Values.Values.FirstOrDefault();
        this.PageConfiguration = GetPageConfiguration(pageName.ToString());

        WrapperManager wm = GetWrapperManager(this.PageConfiguration.Id);
        ViewData["WrapperTop"] = wm.WrapperPartOne;
        ViewData["WrapperBottom"] = wm.WrapperPartTwo;

        base.Initialize(rc);
    }
}
```

And then in the Master page:

```
<%= (string)ViewData["WrapperTop"] %>

    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>    

<%= (string)ViewData["WrapperBottom"] %>
```